# Need help making a sphere move in parabola as part of a projectile simulator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, projectile

Hi I'm currently working on a school computer science project for which I have decided to make a simple projectile simulator, where the user just provides the initial launch speed, the launch angle, and gravity.
So far I've tried to make a script that uses these values to calculate a trajectory pattern and change the y and z position of a sphere across a plane over time.

```
public class SphereJump : MonoBehaviour{

    public float gravity = 9.8f;
    public float InitialSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float LaunchAngle = 45.0f;

    public Transform Sphere;

    void Start () {

        float InitialX = Mathf.Sin(LaunchAngle) * InitialSpeed;
        float InitialY = Mathf.Cos(LaunchAngle) * InitialSpeed;

        float Range = Mathf.Sin(2*LaunchAngle)*Mathf.Pow(InitialSpeed,2)/gravity;

        float MaxHeight = Mathf.Sin(LaunchAngle) * Mathf.Pow(InitialSpeed, 2) / 2 * gravity;

        float FlightTime = Range / InitialX;

        float ElapsedTime = 0;

        while (ElapsedTime < FlightTime)
        {
            float NewPositionX = transform.position.z+InitialX*ElapsedTime;
            float NewPositionY = transform.position.y +InitialY -gravity / 2*ElapsedTime;

            Sphere.Translate(0f, NewPositionY, NewPositionX);

            ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

}
```

Being completely new to Unity, in my head this should mathematically work, however when I run the game either nothing happens or the sphere object disappears. At the start it's position is (1, 0.5, 1) - which is just 0.5 above the plane it's sitting on - and as far as I'm aware the script is correctly attached. A warning also comes up saying "Due to floating point precision limitations...". Would using Vector3 help? Have I confused the script entirely?

Comment: Normally, you don't do anything on `Start`, you use `Update` for logic like this.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Seems to have run the script properly this time however it says that the object is now too far, would you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should go in an `Update()` you can add that method yourself and move the code.

as for your second question:

Vector 3 is a coordinate system for a point position in 3d space, X,Y and Z! you will need a z coordinate to denote depth, or unity dosnt know where to place your object

so:

```
Vector3 newPos= new Vector3(x,y,z);
```

z can remain constant if you dont want distance from the camera to vary.

```
Vector3 newPos= new Vector3(transform.position.z+InitialX*ElapsedTime,transform.position.y +InitialY -gravity / 2*ElapsedTime,z);
```

however,

in unity there is a component called rigidbody. attaching this to your object will add gravity and physics.

you can then get the rigidbody in script:

`RigidBody body = this.GameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>();`

then you can do:

```
body.AddForce(position,direction,force);
```

or `body.gravity=3;`

or several other adjustments to incorperate your physics challenge.